# Reading from parquet is slower than csv -pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to pySpark. I'm trying to optimize my program's execution time on local mode. I've read somewhere that saving a `dataframe` to parquet and then loading it again, before doing any transformations on it , reduces execution time although I don't understand why. Also, in the process of doing that I noticed that it takes longer to load from a parquet than a `csv`. I repartitioned and coalsced my data to minimize the loading times in the example below (8 partitions - data size: roughly 400kB).

My main question is: Are there any guidelines on how to increase my program's performance and why does parquet take longer time to load than csv?

here is an example
[image]

This is my config:

```py
spark.driver.bindAddress: localhost
spark.ui.port: 4040
spark.driver.memory: "12g"
spark.driver.memoryOverhead: 4096
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 8
spark.default.parallelism: 8
spark.master: "local[8]"
# spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin: false
```

Comment: I would expect parquet to have a bit higher initial overhead than CSV.  400k is pretty small so you may be hitting that.  I'd be curious to see the numbers for a much larger file.

Comment: but queries executed on this small csv would take longer than a same-sized parquet right?

Comment: @VectorXY any updates on the same Vector , I would love to know what are the results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell reading from parquet is slower than reading from CSV just by one run with a very small dataset. The result needs to be consistent and fair, i.e: when you running on your local computer, you need to make sure no other tasks are running (and taking memory) while you're reading (so, what if OS update is running on the background while you're reading from parquet). My suggestion is benchmark it over and over, using a bigger dataset if possible, running in a dedicated machine without disrupting by any other tasks etc

Comment: thanks for the input but my question is that does spark deserialises the parquet format before reading , I guess I read somewhere that it does not deserialize the csv file while reading it from an s3 directory biut it does for the parquet. So processing parquet would be more time consuming even tho its a big data set ? Please share your feedback on this or of you have any link for the same which can show the analysis